# Scraping inside of a the description of the opening div tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=6096

Some of the needed information is within an onmouesover end within the opening div tag,

```
<div onmouseover="toggle('clue_J_2_1', 'clue_J_2_1_stuck', '<em class="correct_response">a treadmill</em><br /><br /><table width="100%"><tr><td class="right">Caitlin</td></tr></table>')"....>
```

More specifically, I need the em tag with class "correct_response" but searching for an em tag and searching for anything with class "correct_response" gives me no results, I assume because it lies within the description of the div.

Anyone have an ideas on what I could do to get that em tag?

Comment: While I'm not certain if it would be flexible enough, you could use a simple regex to isolate the HTML within the description, and parse that using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to the first comment. I used regular expressions and found a specific group of text that surrounded what I was looking for after I converted the div into a text, then used re.search with a .group(1) afterwords to single out exactly what I needed.